# Proof of comparison test for improper integrals with boundaries $a=0$ and $b=1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have the following task:

**Comparison Lemma**. Suppose $-\infty \leq a \lt b \leq \infty$ and that $f,F$ are continuous on $(a,b)$. If the improper integrl $\int^b_aF(x)dx$ converges and $|f(x)| \leq F(x) , \forall x \in (a,b)$, then the improper integral $\int^b_af(x)dx$ converges as well.

Prove the test for the case $a=0,b=1$.

Here's how I try to prove it:

If $\int^1_0F(x)dx$ converges then $\int^1_0F(x)dx=A$ for some $A \in \Bbb R_{+}$ and since $$|f(x)| \leq F(x) \Leftrightarrow \int^1_0|f(x)|dx \leq \int^1_0F(x)dx=A\Leftrightarrow \int^1_0|f(x)|dx\leq A\Leftrightarrow|\int^1_0f(x)dx|\leq\int^1_0|f(x)|dx\leq A\Leftrightarrow -A\leq\int^1_0f(x)dx\leq A$$

And hence $\int^1_0f(x)dx$ converges

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Several of the $\iff$ are false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just say that if $\int_0^1|f|$ converges, then $\int_0^1|f|\leq A$. Not that $\int_0^1|f|$ converges.

---

**Hint**

Remark that if $y\in (a,b)$, then $$x\mapsto \int_y^x|f|,$$
in increasing and upper bounded. Also, $$y\mapsto \int_y^1|f|$$
is decreasing and lower bounded.

Comment: No, I say that if $\int_0^1|f|\leq A$ then $\int_0^1|f|$ converges. Is that wrong?

Comment: No, you proved that if $\int_0^1|f|$ converges, then $\int_0^1|f|\leq A$. The reason, is that you wrote $\int_0^1|f|$ without caring out if it makes sense or not (it could be infinite). But indeed, if it converges, then $\int_0^1|f|\leq A$. In somehow, you supposed that $\int_0^1|f|$ converges to prove that it converges. @Marina

Comment: If you prefer, at this stage, the only thing that you can say is that $$\int_x^y|f|\leq \int_x^y|F|\leq \int_0^1|F|,$$ and thus $$\int_x^y|f|\leq \int_0^1|F|$$ for all $x,y\in (0,1)$, $x<y$. But you can't say $$\int_0^1|f|\leq \int_0^1|F|.$$ Just an example, even if $0\leq 2+(-1)^n\leq 3$ but you can't write $\lim_{n\to \infty }2+(-1)^n$ since it doesn't exist. Recall that if $f:(a,b]\to \mathbb R$, then $\int_a^b |f|:=\lim_{x\to a^+}\int_x^b|f|.$ @Marina

Comment: ok, so then the proof in this link http://mathonline.wikidot.com/comparison-test-for-improper-integral-convergence-divergence is wrong?

Comment: @Marina: I would say yes it's wrong strictly speaking. So, for novice yes it's wrong. Strictly speaking it's written : since $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)\leq 1$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ exist, which is a non sense. To write $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ you first have to prove that it makes sense (i.e. that it exist). But when you get more used to it, it's fine (but not very rigorous), because the implicit argument is : since $x\mapsto \int_b^x g$ is increasing and upper-bounded then it converges. But I highly recommand you to not write such a proof a be more explicit. I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!